# C# Html parsing HtmlAgilityPack not working

Tags: c#, html, html-table

I am trying to read html table in order to read and change table with using HtmlAgilityPack. I tried with very different websites but my code does not work.

> SelectSingleNode function returns  null. Also when I call SelectNodes instead of SelectSingleNode, result is null again.

Example link
http://www.uefa.com/livescores/ has a table. How can I read this table?

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("http://www.uefa.com/livescores/");
var result = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table");
```

Comment: _but my code does not work_ What does not work? What errors do you see? Describe what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `LoadHtml` method which is used to load a HTML string, not load HTML from a URL.  However, the `Load` method does not appear to support loading content from a URL and you may need to download the HTML separately and then load it it into the HtmlDocument class to use it.

For example:

```
var url = "http://www.uefa.com/livescores/";
var content = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(url);

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(content);
var hn = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table");
```

You can also use the `HtmlWeb` utility class:

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url);
var hn = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table");
```

Comment: If output of parsing is wrong, is there anything to fix? Because mine result is not true. All of the </td> </tr> are at end of result. I could not share my actual web page. But result like below
    <td><a href=test>test</a>
<td alıgn="right">7
<tr><td><a href=test">test</a>
    <td><a href="a.html">test</a>
<td alıgn="right">5
....
</td></td></tr></td></td></td></tr></td></td></td></tr></td></td></td>

Comment: If you have a valid HTML document, you can use any XPath statement to select the markup that you need.

Comment: There is a hr tag inside html, so xpath also gives error. When I remove hr tags manually it fixes. Because hr does not have any closing like </hr> Am i wrong?